# VScode keybindings.json binding ctrl + numbersign

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to bind the key-combination `Ctrl`+`#` in VSCode as follows:

```json
// File: keybindings.json
[
  //...
  {
    "key":     "ctrl+#",
    "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
    "when":    "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
  }
]
```

I tried a view variations, like `ctrl`+`hash|hashtag|numbersign|numbersymbol` etc., but VSCode always prompts:

> Key or key sequence (separated by space)
> You won't be able to produce this key combination under your current keyboard layout.

Thanks in advance for any tips, links, hints, and answers!

Comment: to find the key-combo-string to use in the key binding use the key shortcut GUI and check button **Record Keys** and then type wanted key combo, also allows key prefix

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/050ec25b7ad02886562f720b0a9d3f8e81a4a62a/src/vs/base/common/keyCodes.ts#L552

Answer (score 0):

After trying to temporarily overwrite the default binding `ctrl+shift+7`
in `>Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`,
VSCode additional appended the new binding:

```json
[
    // ...
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+7",
        "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+[Backslash]",
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

[image]

Seems like `[Backslash]` did the trick!

**Edit**: I also found a [list of binable keys](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-layoutindependent-bindings), which was confusing at first, since I knew that the `#` can be bound (this was the default behavior on Windows and I wanted the same on Ubuntu), but the number symbol wasn't listed!